# Update user location.longitude in TextField, jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin

Iam retrieving the users location (longitude and lattitude). I made a class LocationLiveData, this is working fine.
What i want is to show the longitude in a TextField, so when the location of the user changes it has to update the TextField.
At this moment the textfield is only updating the longitude when i trigger a recompose of the composable.

It seems like there is going something wrong in the observeAsState()

The composable:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(application:Application) {

    //connect to viewModel
    val viewModelLocations: ApplicationViewModel = ApplicationViewModel(application = application)

    //observe the data in viewModel
    val location by viewModelLocations.getLocationLiveData().observeAsState()


    Column() {
         OutlinedTextField(value = location.longitude, onValueChange = { location.longitude = it})
        Text("The textfield has this text: " + location.longitude)

    
}
    
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class ApplicationViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
  

    private val locationLiveData = LocationLiveData(context = application)


    fun getLocationLiveData(): LocationLiveData {
        var data = locationLiveData
        return data

    }

    //start the location updates
    fun startLocationUpdates() {
        locationLiveData.startLocationUpdates()
    }


}
```

Class LocationLiveData (here iam retrieving the users location)
Note: if i print the .value its printing the userslocation longitude and lattitude

```
class LocationLiveData(var context: Context): MutableLiveData<LocationDetails>() {


    private val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
     
            return
        }
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
            location -> location.also {
                setLocationData(it)

        }

        }
    }

      fun startLocationUpdates() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())

    }

    private fun setLocationData(location: Location?) {
        //location.let (maak een functie, deze wordt alleen uitgvoerd indien locatie niet null is)
        location?.let { it ->
            //value is observed in LiveData
            value = LocationDetails(
                longitude = it.longitude.toString(),
                lattitude = it.latitude.toString()
            )
            println("value $value")
        }

    }

    //onInactive als de LiveData niet meer geobserveerd wordt
    //we willen unsubscriben van de location updates (moet dus stoppen met updaten)
    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }

    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
            println("we have a new location result")
            locationResult ?: return //als er een result is dan prima, zo niet dan just return (elvis operator)
            for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                setLocationData(location = location)

            }
        }
    }

    companion object {

        val ONE_MINUTE: Long = 1000
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
        val locationRequest : com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = ONE_MINUTE
            fastestInterval = ONE_MINUTE/4
            priority = LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }


    }

}
```